# Redis pipeline with scan and get

Tags: redis, pipeline

I have a construct like this:

```
while {
   keys, cursor, err = redis.scan(cursor, "bla:*", 100)
   for keys {
       res = redis.get(keys[i])
       ....
   } 
   ....
}
```

Is it possible to put the scan and get commands into pipeline?  if yes, how can I do it? i have some problems with performance.

Answer (score 0):

NO, you cannot put SCAN into pipeline. Because the 2nd scan depends on the 1st scan result, and you have to get the reply of first scan before you can send the second scan command.

In order to improve performance, you have two options:

1. Put these GET commands into a pipeline
2. Use MGET command to get multiple keys.

Comment: yes, I use pipeline for GET, but scan causes performance problems.